# Sense resistor connection

Tags: lipo

I'm looking throw bq76940 datasheet and I've found such connection of sense resistor:

[image: Sense resistor connection]

What is the purpose of the additional resistors and capacitors? Why all 3 capacitors are required?

Comment: I think noise filtering. It will avoid controller from doing weird things if current is drawn in pulse from the battery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a lowpass filter. It filter out common mode noise (resistors and those capacitors connected to the earth) and differential noise (mid capacitor and resistors)